# create random colors that can be instantly distinguished by humans

Tags: random, colors

I was looking on stackoverflow for an answer, but wasn't really satisfied with what I found.

I need several different colors. I only find out the number of different colors I need at runtime.

I created the colors here now with 3 random numbers each. But as you can see, the two light green / brown colors are already quite difficult to distinguish from each other.
In the worst case, it can happen that the values are completely the same or differ only in one number.

So I wanted to ask, how do you create colors in a colorspace or in a color scheme, so that the generated colors can be distinguished?

And as an additional question, how can you create them so that they are softened, because you don't want an object to be immediately eye-catching?

I wrote this in python but any answer would help me so I can write it then by my own in python.

[image]

Comment: Rather than coding your problem to use random RGB/CMY values, you might consider making color selection a discrete problem based on a [colorblind friendly palette](https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/).

Comment: Can you give links to which Stack Overflow questions you found unhelpful?

Comment: I discuss the matter of distinguishable colors at the following link: http://peteroupc.github.io/colorgen.html#Visually_Distinct_Colors